# Email address format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-scraping

I have an email address in a sql table in the following format:

```
&#99;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#107;&#064;&#119;&#101;&#97;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#115;&#046;&#111;&#114;&#103;&#046;&#117;&#107;
```

How can I convert it to the proper format?

I see it displays perfectly on a webpage but anywhere else it's like this. I am assuming it's codes for alphabets etc. (html) which get converted, but how do I update my table with the proper emails?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you after a SQL script to update all the values, or just a way to view the values of that column?

Comment: Just an FYI, but they probably encoded the emails to prevent web scraping.

Comment: I think this is like we write > as &lgt; and so on

Comment: Those are the `CHAR()` values for the characters...

Comment: @DaveShaw I want sql script to update them once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode.aspx) method, you should be able to write a loop to process all your data or write an extended stored procedure and call it from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small amount - you can use a tool like this:  http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

You can use the information found at http://www.lookuptables.com/ to write code to decode it yourself, or like Tony has suggested; use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode`

I don't know of any good way to do this in with SQL - I'd write a small app to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-time fix for this one record: As you say it displays correctly on the screen, then cool: Display it on whatever screen that is, then copy and paste that value back into a database update, either a screen or a one-shot query.

If you're software is putting these escapes into the email address before saving to the database, I'd say: Don't. This is a bad idea, because then you can't search it or manipulate it. Store all values in "real" text. Do your HTML escaping when you are laying out a screen. Actually in ASP.NET I think most of the display functions do this automatically; some have flags to tell it to NOT HTML escape.

Addendum: I see Tony's answer assumes all your email addresses look like this. Is this correct, or is it just one? If it's all, then my suggestion for fixing one is impractical, you do indeed want to write a little program that loops through the db and fixes them all with HtmlDecode.